# C++ 32767 text-based game

Tags: c++

help, whenever i run my game, whenever i call the display() function on a weapon, it always returns as 32767! How can I make it so that when the display function is called, it prints that weapons power to the console? thanks in advance!

---

```
   //a SETIsoft game

#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

// GLOBAL VARIABLES
string charname;

//NAV CLASS
class nav
{
public:
    int navatk;
    int navdef;
    int navspd;
    int navluk;
    int navhpo;
    int navepo;

//CLASS MEMBER FUNCTIONS
    void INIT(int navattack, int navdefense, int navspeed, int navhp, int navluck, int navenergy);
    void display();
};
//NAV MEMBER FUNCTION DEFINITIONS
void nav::INIT(int navattack, int navdefense, int navspeed, int navhp, int navluck, int navenergy)
{
    navatk = navattack;
    navdef = navdefense;
    navspd = navspeed;
    navhpo = navhp;
    navluk = navluck;
    navepo = navenergy;

}
void nav::display()
{
    cout<<"attack: "<< navatk <<endl;
    cout<<"defense: "<< navdef <<endl;
    cout<<"speed: "<< navspd <<endl;
    cout<<"health points: "<< navhpo <<endl;
    cout<<"luck: "<< navluk <<endl;
    cout<<"energy points: "<< navepo <<endl;

}
//BUG CLASS
class bug
{
public:
    int bugatk;
    int bugdef;
    int bugluk;
    int bugspd;
    int bughpo;
    int bugepo;

//CLASS MEMBER FUNCTIONS
    void INIT(int bugattack, int bugdefense, int bugspeed, int bughp, int bugluck, int bugenergy);
    void display();
};
//BUG MEMBER FUNCTION DEFINITIONS

void bug::INIT(int bugattack, int bugdefense, int bugspeed, int bughp, int bugluck, int bugenergy)
{
    bugatk = bugattack;
    bugdef = bugdefense;
    bugspd = bugspeed;
    bughpo = bughp;
    bugluk = bugluck;
    bugepo = bugenergy;

}

void bug::display()
{
    cout<<"attack: "<< bugatk <<endl;
    cout<<"defense: "<< bugdef <<endl;
    cout<<"speed: "<< bugspd <<endl;
    cout<<"health points: "<< bughpo <<endl;
    cout<<"luck: "<< bugluk <<endl;
    cout<<"energy points: "<< bugepo <<endl;    
}

//WEAPON CLASS
class userweap
{
public:    
    int id;
    int power;
    int cost;
    string descrip;

//CLASS MEMBER FUNCTIONS
    void INIT(int id, int weappower, int weapcost);
    void display();
    string equip();
};
//CLASS MEMEBER FUNCTION DEFINITIONS

void userweap::INIT(int id, int weappower, int weapcost)
{
    weappower = power;
    weapcost = cost;
}
void userweap::display()
{
    cout<<"power: " << power <<endl;

}
string userweap::equip()
{
    string equipped;
    equipped = id;
    return equipped;
}
//GLOBAL HELPER FUNCTIONS
void intro();
string choice(nav & user);
void btutorial();
string allgood();
void checkstats(bug & simbug, nav & user);
void simbugmake(bug & simbug);
void regcannonmake(userweap & regcannonweap);
void beamswordmake(userweap & beamsword);
void laserbowmake(userweap & laserbow);
void flyingfistmake(userweap & flyingfist);
void razordiscmake(userweap & razordisc);
void blockpunchmake(userweap & blockpunch);
void flaremake(userweap & flare);
void wavemake(userweap & wave);
void whipmake(userweap & whip);
void mindshotmake(userweap & mindshot);
void weapons(userweap & regcannon);

//MAIN FUNCTION
int main(){
    nav dummynav;
    userweap dummyweap;
    intro();
    while( choice(dummynav) == "no") cout<< "let me show you them again" << endl;
    btutorial();
    while( allgood() == "no");
    sleep(1);
    weapons(dummyweap); 
    return 0;
}

void intro()
{
    cout<<"what's your name again?"<<endl;
    cin>>charname;
    cout<<"hello, "<<charname<<endl;
    sleep(2);
    cout<<"welcome to the pentagon"<<endl;
    sleep(1);
    cout<<"year: 2050 C.E." << endl;
    sleep(1);
    cout<<"you have been nominated to control a 'navigator.' a digital fighting warrior that we use to fight the rebellion."<<endl;
    sleep(1);
    cout<<"..."<<endl;
    sleep(1);
    cout<<"what's this? you've never heard of the rebellion before?"<<endl;
    sleep(1);
    cout<<"the year was 2015, when the citizens of the united states of america rose up against the government. little did they know, the government had installed a top-secret project called 'SEVEN' (or s.ecretly e.liminate v.iolent e.lectronic n.ews) into the world wide web . they used this successfully to break up riots by intercepting internet-bound messages. soon after, the rebellion's top scientists figured out the programs weak-spots, and created viruses 'bugs' to destroy said program."<<endl;
    sleep(12);
    cout<<"that's where you come in." << endl;
    sleep(1);
    cout<<"we've created an elite squad of web 'navigators' to destroy any viruses we encounter." <<endl;
    sleep(1);
    cout<<"you will be tasked with controlling one of these 'navigators' to end the rebellion once and for all."<<endl;
    sleep(1);
    cout<<"let me show you them"<<endl;
}

string choice(nav & user)
{
    sleep(1);
    cout<<"..."<<endl;
    sleep(1);
    cout<<"bladenav: a well balanced navigator that can wield a multitude of de-bugging weapons"<<endl;
    cout<<"arrownav: a speed-oriented navigator that can attack stealthily from far range"<<endl;
    cout<<"fistsnav: an attack-heavy navigator with low speed but with a variety of high-power weapons"<<endl;
    cout<<"shellnav: an extremely high defense navigator with low speed and attack "<<endl;
    cout<<"golemnav: a high attack, high defense navigator with low speed, and a narrow range of attacks "<< endl;
    cout<<"flamenav: a navigator with flame-based attacks with relatively large luck"<<endl;
    cout<<"aqueonav: a navigator with aqua-based attacks with relatively large luck"<<endl;
    cout<<"plantnav: a navigator with plant-based attacks with relatively large luck"<<endl;
    cout<<"psychnav: a high hit points navigator with indirect attacking abilities"<<endl;
    cout<<"chicknav: a navigator with terrible stats all around and no redeeming qualities whatsoever except for it's 100% luck stat."<<endl;
    sleep(3);
    cout<<"you may choose one and only one to control. pick wisely"<<endl;
    string navchoice;
    cin>> navchoice;
    if (navchoice == "bladenav") user.INIT(50, 50, 50, 100, 10, 40);
    else if (navchoice =="arrownav") user.INIT(55, 30, 65, 100, 10, 40);
    else if (navchoice =="fistsnav") user.INIT(80, 55, 10, 115, 10, 30);
    else if (navchoice =="shellnav") user.INIT(25, 80, 25, 120, 10, 40);
    else if (navchoice =="golemnav") user.INIT(70, 70, 10, 100, 10, 40);
    else if (navchoice =="flamenav") user.INIT(50, 50, 40, 100, 15, 45);
    else if (navchoice =="aqueonav") user.INIT(50, 50, 40, 100, 15, 45);
    else if (navchoice =="plantnav") user.INIT(50, 50, 40, 100, 15, 45);
    else if (navchoice =="psychnav") user.INIT(20, 30, 30, 150, 10, 50);
    else if (navchoice =="chicknav") user.INIT(20, 20, 20, 100, 100, 40);
    sleep(1);
    user.display();
    sleep(1);
    cout<<"is this you're final selection, "<< charname <<"?"<<endl;
    string yesno;
    cin >> yesno;
    return yesno;
}

void btutorial()
{
    userweap dummyweap;
    regcannonmake(dummyweap);
    beamswordmake(dummyweap);
    laserbowmake(dummyweap);
    flyingfistmake(dummyweap);
    razordiscmake(dummyweap);
    blockpunchmake(dummyweap);
    flaremake(dummyweap);
    wavemake(dummyweap);
    whipmake(dummyweap);
    mindshotmake(dummyweap);    
    cout<<"now that you've chosen your navigator, you should probably learn how to use it."<<endl;
    sleep(1);
    cout<<"..."<<endl;
    sleep(1);
    cout<<"when you find an enemy 'bug', battle mode is initiated."<<endl;
    sleep(1);
    cout<<" ______________________________________________________"<<endl;
    cout<<"|ATTACK| WEAPONS | ITEMS | FLEE | CHECK STATS | DEFEND |"<<endl;
    cout<<"|______|_________|_______|______|_____________|________|"<<endl;
    sleep(1);
    cout<<"then you select an option. choosing 'attack' attacks the opponent. The damage you deal is equal to the weapon's power added to your attack, then subtracted by the enemy's defense. 'weapons' accesses your de-bugging arsenal, 'items' allows you to view and use your one-use items, 'check stats' checks both your and the enemy's health points and stats, and 'defend' doubles your defense for the next turn, but takes up a turn. activating 'flee' will end the encounter unless your speed is lower than the 'bug's'."<<endl;
    sleep(10);
    cout<<"then, after your turn is over, your oppenent will either attack or defend."<< endl;
}

string allgood()
{
    sleep(5);
    cout<< "all good?" <<endl;
    string yesno;
    cin >> yesno;
    return yesno;
}

//WEAPON CREATION
void regcannonmake(userweap & regcannon)
{
    regcannon.INIT(1,5,0);
}
void beamswordmake(userweap & beamsword)
{
    beamsword.INIT(2,7,1);
}
void laserbowmake(userweap & laserbow)
{
    laserbow.INIT(3,6,1);
}
void flyingfistmake(userweap & flyingfist)
{
    flyingfist.INIT(4,8,1);
}
void razordiscmake(userweap & razordisc)
{
    razordisc.INIT(5,4,1);
}
void blockpunchmake(userweap & blockpunch)
{
    blockpunch.INIT(6,5,1);
}
void flaremake(userweap & flare)
{
    flare.INIT(7,5,1);
}
void wavemake(userweap & wave)
{
    wave.INIT(8,5,1);
}
void whipmake(userweap & whip)
{
    whip.INIT(9,5,1);
}
void mindshotmake(userweap & mindshot)
{
    mindshot.INIT(10,7,1);
}
//CHECKSTATS
void checkstats(bug & simbug, nav & user)
{
    cout<<"your stats:"<< endl;
    user.display();
    cout<<""<< endl;
    cout<<"bug's stats:"<< endl;
    simbug.display();
}
void weapons(userweap & regcannon)
{

    sleep(1);
    cout<<"weapons:"<<endl;
    cout<<"regcannon"<<endl;
    sleep(1);
    cout<< "pick one" <<endl;
    string weapchoice;
    cin >> weapchoice;
    if (weapchoice == "regcannon")
    {
        regcannon.display();
        regcannon.equip();
        while( allgood() == "no");
        cout<< charname << " equipped the regcannon" <<endl; 
    }

}
void flee();
void flee()
{

}
void defend(nav & user);
void defend(nav & user)
{

}
void items();
void items()
{

}
bool battle(nav & user);
bool battle(nav & user)
{
    bug simbug;
    simbug.INIT(10,10,10,10,10,10);
    cout<<simbug.bugatk<<endl;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Please reduce this to a minimal example that demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your code starts to build up like this, it becomes easier and easier to miss small nuances. In this case, you've fallen afoul of a problem with two sets of variables that kind of mean the same thing but don't distinguish themselves as to who is on which side of a particular operation.

In your `userweap::INIT` function you are receiving two values to initialize the object with, weappower and weapcost. But instead of initializing them, you copy the data from the object into the parameters and then return.

```
void userweap::INIT(int id, int weappower /*input*/, int weapcost /*input*/)
{
    weappower /*input*/ = power /*member value*/;
    weapcost /*input*/ = cost /*member value*/;
}
```

That's the exact opposite of what you intended to do. As a result, your member values `power` and `cost` never have values deliberately assigned and your 32767 is random data from 'undefined behavior'.

Help yourself avoid this: give member variables a prefix, like 'm_' or 'm'

```
int m_power; // member variable that stores power.
```

Now your code will carry some additional indication of what you are doing:

```
void userweap::INIT(int id, int weappower, int weapcost)
{
    weappower = m_power;
    weapcost = m_cost;
}
```

plus you would be able to avoid the 'weap' prefix here:

```
void userweap::INIT(int id, int power, int cost)
{
    power = m_power;
    cost = m_cost;
}
```

Much easier to see the mistake, the correct code being:

```
void userweap::INIT(int id, int power, int cost)
{
    m_power = power;
    m_cost = cost;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You set the parameters not your members, therefor `power` is uninitialized.

```
void userweap::INIT(int id, int weappower, int weapcost)
{
    weappower = power;
    weapcost = cost;
}
```

should be:

```
void userweap::INIT(int id, int weappower, int weapcost)
{
    power = weappower;
    cost = weapcost;
}
```

Another thing: Use a constructor!

```
 userweap::userweap(int id, int weappower, int weapcost)
 : power(weappower),
   cost(weapcost)
 {
 }
```

And next time please get to the point (dont post a "wall of code")

Answer (score 1):

Change the lines:

```
weappower = power;
weapcost = cost;
```

They should be:

```
power = weappower;
cost = weapcost;
```

As it stands now, you never assign to `power`, so it is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

```
void userweap::INIT(int id, int weappower, int weapcost)
{
    weappower = power;
    weapcost = cost;
}
void userweap::display()
{
    cout<<"power: " << power <<endl;

}
```

In your INIT(), you're assigning the value of the member variable to the parameter. It needs to be the other way around.